# How to permanently set a local Prefect config file?

Tags: prefect

As per the `Prefect` [Configuration guide](https://docs.prefect.io/core/concepts/configuration.html#environment-variables) I've set a local config file (i.e. in my current working directory) via `export PREFECT__USER_CONFIG_PATH="./config.toml"`, however, this requires the environmental variable to be set each shell session.

I tried setting the config in a Python script with `prefect.config.user_config_path = "./config.toml"` but this doesn't seem to load the config file in the same way as `export` because:

> (from docs) "The configuration file is parsed when Prefect is first imported and is available as a live object in prefect.config."

For my dummy `config.toml` data:

```
[api]
host = "localhost"
port = "5432"
url = "https://${api.host}:${api.port}"
```

`prefect.config` via environmental variable:

```
...'task_runner': {'default_class': 'prefect.engine.task_runner.TaskRunner'}}, 'api': {'host': 'localhost', 'port': 5432, 'url': 'https://localhost:5432'}, 'user_config_path': './config.toml'}>
```

`prefect.config` via script:

```
...'task_runner': {'default_class': 'prefect.engine.task_runner.TaskRunner'}}, 'user_config_path': './config.toml'}>
```

So `config.toml` variables aren't loaded in second case

Any ideas?

(Application: I want to set a 'Prefect' secret in my local `config.toml` file hidden from source control)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you want the `config.toml` file in your present working directory?  The default location for user config files is `~/.prefect/config.toml`, so if you place your configuration there it will work with no additional setup.

If you do need the configuration file in your present working directory, you might try adding the `export` statement to your `~/.bashrc` (or whatever shell equivalent you might need) so that it's always in your environment.

Comment: Thanks @chriswhite that'll do the trick!  One use case for having `config.toml` in the base directory of a library (such as [drem](https://github.com/codema-dev/drem)) rather than homedir is to enable library-specific `config.toml` secrets or other and avoiding altering `~/.bashrc` equivalents by remaining in Python/toml.  I was thinking of prompting the user to enter their email (a secret) and storing it in a local `config.toml` - not an urgent use case I imagine!